# Best graphics program

Tags: software-recommendation, image-editor

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and i am web developer and designer. I am using linux cause sass and terminal usage when developing, i would use mac but don't have money to buy it. I need good graphics program for web site designing. I was using photoshop and i am having troubles installing it through wine. I tried gimp for designing but it just won't work cause i am new to gimp and it is hard for me to do anything, even typing text with proper font is hard for me. So you guys recommend me what is a good graphics program.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please include in your question what your question actually is. I assume that you are asking for recommended graphic design programs, but please confirm by editing your question to include what you are asking.

Comment: *Any* other application then Photoshop would require some time to get used to, like Gimp. ALso, it is a bit unclear if you are looking for design (vector?) or image processing?

Comment: https://krita.org this one seemed nice

Comment: I need a raster program.

Comment: Then Gimp seems to be *the* application, at least one of the most matured.

Comment: @LeonLaci which version of PhotoShop did you try to get working with Wine?

Comment: There seems to be lots of information on the Wine official website on problems with using Wine and PhotoShop and some workarounds etc: http://wiki.winehq.org/AdobePhotoshop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a "best" for anything. Just pick what suits you best.
If you don't like gimp and/or don't find you have the time to learn it, you should search around for alternatives, though, I can't assure you you'll be able to use any of them without some relearning.
I always find Arch's list of applications worth a look: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications#Graphics_and_image_manipulation
Otherwise you have alternative.to: http://alternativeto.net/software/gimp/?platform=linux